# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined on jQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate form input to allow only specified file type

```
  $("#resumeFile").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            extension: "doc|pdf|docx",
            messages: {
                required: "Please select File",
                extension: "Accepted formats pdf, doc or docx"
            }
        });
```

When I remove `extension: "doc|csv|pdf|docx",` it works perfectly fine , with `extension` check its giving error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Comment: `extension: /doc|pdf|docx/,` use regular expression then.

Comment: @jai : Not working

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` - does it give a file and line number for the error, and a stack trace ... use unminified versions of your external libraries, and you may be able to see exactly where the trouble is using **developer tools** console/debugger - the code you posted is not really enough for anything but stabs in the dark

Comment: Assuming you are using jquery-validate `Current version: 1.15.0` then under requirements` it says `jQuery, tested with 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, 1.11.1` which version of jQuery do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your best clue and explains it perfectly:

> When I remove `extension: "doc|csv|pdf|docx"`, it works perfectly fine, with `extension` check its giving error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

The `extension` method is not defined because it's not part of the default set of rules.  You have to include [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/additional-methods.js), as this is where the `extension` rule is located.